# Update Table Column from Old and New Table Reference

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day,

Basically, I have a system that is referencing to old tables. But the problem is, I have a new table (identical to old but the primary key is different) and I want to reference my system to the new table. The current system already stored the foreign key from the old table. But I want to update those foreign ids to properly reference to the new table. The problem is, the old table is composed of hundreds of records and I have no idea what query should I use to update the system table referencing to new table.

Old Table columns with sample data (That has hundreds of record)

```
| CompanyId |      Name      |
|   4301    |   Apple Inc.   | 
|   4302    |   Microsoft    |
```

New Table columns with sample data (Same data with old but different primary key)

```
| CompanyId |      Name      |
|   1002    |   Apple Inc.   | 
|   1003    |   Microsoft    |
```

Here's the my sample table that has foreign key from the old company table.

```
| CustomerId |  CompanyId  |  CustomerName  |
|     1      |     4301    |  John E. Doe   |
|     2      |     4301    |  Lorem K. Fox  |
```

The only procedure I know is manually create a query one-by-one.

`UPDATE Customer SET CompanyId=1002 WHERE CustomerId=1`

But this is a bad idea because I'm dealing with hundreds of records.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `join`.  Assuming the names are the same:

```
update s
    set s.companyid = nt.companid
    from samples s join
         oldtable ot
         on s.companyid = ot.companyid join
         newtable nt
         on ot.name = nt.name;
```

Now some cautions:

- You need to drop the foreign key constraint for this to work.  You should add it back afterwards.
- This may not update all the rows in the table, if some of the names do not match.
- If not all rows are updated, then the resulting ids could be mixed -- some to the old table, some to the new table.

You do specify that the tables "are identical", so I would guess that these are not problems for your particular situation.

Comment: But I don't want to based on name, just with ids. Because I can't rely with the characters of the name

Comment: @AppleCiderYummy . . . (1) Your question says that the tables are "identical" which implies that the names are the same.  (2) You need a way to align the old and new tables, so if the names are different, you cannot reliably do what you want.

Comment: if you want to do it with ids, you need to create a mapping table to go from the old id to the new id.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to create a mapping table to link the ids from the old table to the new table.

So in your example:

```
         mappingtable
| oldcompanyid | newcompanyid |
|    4301      |     1001     |
|    4302      |     1002     |
```

Then you can update your customer table by joining from the old key to the new key:

```
update s
    set s.companyid = nt.companyid
    from samples s join
         mappingtable t on s.companyid=t.oldcompanyid join 
         newtable nt
         on t.newcompanyid = nt.companyid
```

Comment: I think creating another table called `mappingtable` is also time consuming. I'm talking about hundreds of records here

Comment: But you are updating the hundreds of records in the customer table. Presumably you have many less companies to work with? You have to match on something - either the company description, or via a mapped ID.